# How to return variable from observable into another observable type

Tags: android, asynchronous, kotlin, rx-java

I query the youtube api and made several models to map the json with gson converter. Now I want to use repository pattern and unify the return value from my database and from remote, but I have some issues to know how to return a specific variable from an observable in RxJava.

I query the api like this:

```
@GET("playlistItems?part=snippet")
fun getLatestVideosFromPlaylist(@Query("playlistId") playlistId:String, @Query("maxResults") maxResults:String): Observable<YoutubeVideosModel>
```

My models

```
data class YoutubeVideosModel(
    @SerializedName("items")
    val videos: ArrayList<YoutubeVideo>
)

@Entity(tableName = "video")
data class YoutubeVideo(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Int? = null,

    @SerializedName("snippet")
    val video: YoutubeVideoData
)
```

My data source interface

```
interface VideoDataSource {
   fun fetchVideos(playlistId:String) : Observable<ArrayList<YoutubeVideo>>
}
```

From my local data source I return a arrayList of youtubeVideo

```
object VideoLocalSource: VideoDataSource {

override fun fetchVideos(playlistId: String): Observable<ArrayList<YoutubeVideo>> {
    return Observable.fromCallable {
        AppDatabase.getInstance(BaseApp.INSTANCE)?.getVideoDao()!!.fetchAllVideos()
    }
  }
}
```

But from my remote I cannot find how to return the same:

```
object VideoRemoteSource: VideoDataSource {

override fun fetchVideos(playlistId: String, maxResults:String): Observable<ArrayList<YoutubeVideo>> {

    YoutubeApiClient.getYoutubeService().getLatestVideosFromPlaylist(playlistId, maxResults)
            .subscribe {
                videoModel ->
                //Here cannot use return
                return ObservableFromArray(arrayOf(videoModel.videos)
            }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are having difficulty with is the way asynchronous programming requires you to think. Returning an observable inside a subscription callback is not valid. Because you don't know when the subscriber will be called

For a case like this where you want to return an observable of what you are fetching asynchronously, you can use a map like below.

```
object VideoRemoteSource: VideoDataSource {

override fun fetchVideos(playlistId: String): Observable<List<YoutubeVideo>> {

    return youtubeApiService.getLatestVideosFromPlaylist(playlistId, "3")
            .flatMap{
                Observable.fromArray(it.videos)
            }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm trying to convert this code into kotlin but there is no apply function to override, and I can't see how to use it otherwise. Would you know how to convert it in kotlin?

Comment: I think it would be the same syntax with javascript then. I updated the answer

Comment: So in the end in kotlin it works if I do:
     .flatMap{Observable.fromArray(it.videos)}

Comment: Could you send an edit to my code snippet for the kotlin implementation? For everyone that will referance this later on.